# Fastest way to get a row using TableAdapter

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, datarow, tableadapter

From my TableAdapter SELECT statement, I do a

`SELECT StudentID FROM dbo.Student WHERE Email = @Email`

And in my .vb code, I call the function out and do a for each loop like this:

```
Dim myStudentID As Integer

Dim myTable = StudentTableAdapter1.GetStudentID("myEmail@mail.com")
For Each myRow As DataRow In myTable.Rows
    myStudentID = myRow.Item("StudentID")
    MessageBox.Show(myStudentID)
Next
```

However I wish to shorten this further. Is there a way to get the row faster?

Comment: What you mean faster? If you want faster then use `ExecuteScalar` on your query

Answer (score 0):

If you're absolutely sure that you will only return a row, you can do as follows:

```
Dim myStudentID As Integer
Dim myTable = StudentTableAdapter1.GetStudentID("myEmail@mail.com")
myStudentID = myTable(0)("StudentID")
MessageBox.Show(myStudentID)
```